# How do i set a date to locale with react-moment?

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I have to format a date in ReactJs, so i decided to import Moment.js in my project. So I import Moment as a component :

```
import Moment from 'react-moment';
```

In my return :

```
return(
    <Moment locale="fr" format="ll">{item.Date}</Moment>
)
```

But this doesn't work and always return the english date format.
Any idea ?

Thannks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the language you want like:

```
import 'moment/locale/en';
```

And for each new moment just set -

```
moment().locale('en')
```